# cannot change the grid's spacing and offset in GIMP

Tags: configuration, grid, gimp

I'm changing the grid's configuration in GIMP (Preferences -> Default grid). I've increased the spacing from original 10 px to 40px, and the offset as well (from 0 to 10 px).
But the grid appearance in the image just stays the same - still 10 x 10 px cells, no offset as if I didn't do any config.

What could I be missing?

GIMP 2.8.10, Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That configuration is for the default grid settings, for newly created images.
When you work with images in the XCF format, the settings are saved with the image.
So, I suspect you had an image with the factory default settings of 10x10px, saved itas
XCF, changed the GIMP default settings. When reopening that image, the 10x10px grid
configuration was saved along with it, and will be the valid parameters for that image.
You have to reconfigure then in `Image->Configure grid` for each image which has 
the grid settings already saved.

Comment: it has literally taken me _years_ to grok this really, really, reaaaaaaaallly dumb thing that gimp, and nothing else that I've ever seen, does... but it's actually not dumb at all :-( never cared about xcf until 5 days ago